# c - What is a correct way of defining array?

Tags: c, arrays, char

What is the correct way of defining the array in c? The following construction doesn't work,
compiler gives an error "Expected Expression":

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

#define Lookup[9][] = {"00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08"}
```

Comment: Your example in C++, not in plain C...

Comment: Ugh! Don't `#define` data!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to define and initialize your array is

```
char Lookup[][3] = {"00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08"};
```

Each element of the array `Lookup` is itself another array of 3 bytes. Counting with the zero terminator, that's enough space for strings 2 chars long.

The number of elements in the array is available with the expression `sizeof Lookup / sizeof *Lookup`, as in

```
int k;
for (k = 0; k < sizeof Lookup / sizeof *Lookup; k++) {
    printf("element at index %d: %s\n", k, Lookup[k]);
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get rid of zero terminator?

Comment: (I need to make a lookup table for a really fast algorithm, and with zero terminator it will be more complicated and slow)

Comment: If you define the innermost arrays with just 2 bytes, the resulting elements are no longer strings, but it's possible. Not being strings, I like to make it somewhat clearer by using `unsigned char` (or `signed char`) rather than plain `char`: `unsigned char Lookup[][2] = {"00", "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08"};`. **Remember the elements are no longer strings**. The use of `"%s"` in `printf` is an error (as is the use of many functions in `<string.h>`).

Answer (score 2):

To define an array of `int`, for example:

```
int int_array[10];
```

To define and initialise an array of `int`:

```
int int_array[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

Specifying the number of elements is optional if you initialise the array.